# Where is the best place (method) to detect iOS version?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Didn't see it when searching so apologize if I missed it, but I'm curious about the best place to detect iOS version. I see lots of posts about how, but I'm wondering where the best place to to check is.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` makes sense, but my question is, what if the user launches your app, taps home button, upgrades their iOS version, then opens app again? Is `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` called again or just the normal enter foreground methods? This is the one case where I can think of that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` could trip you up.

Comment: Why do you need to check the version at all? Check for features when you need them...

Comment: its a valid point, the one thing I'm thinking is that I'm setting base sdk to 6.1 for other reasons so im wondering if i can check for features like usual, when i don't have that available. that make sense?  so I'm just curious if didfinishlaunching would work or not

Comment: Check whenever you need.

Comment: Andrew, IMHO thats so rare that its almost not worrying about. Put it in the App Delegate in the didFinish. You could always set a NSUserDefaults to a version number and check it in didFinish. If its different than current, you can direct the user to shut down the app and restart.

Comment: Another way to look at it: If the OS gets updated, do you think your app will be killed?

Comment: thanks to all for the help. i agree it's rare, was just curious. I'm thinking about all the people currently upgrading to iOS 7 and wanted to avoid them opening the app and seeing all the ugly UI stuff because I wasn't checking. @user523234 i had heard system version was slow so i was avoiding using it a lot

Comment: Wain, you make a good point and yea, i would think that when you update and restart the phone etc., the app would have to be killed. therefore, didfinishlaunching would be called. so i think putting it there would be fine. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned this is a fairly rare case, but if you really need to check every single time the app is opened; whether it's from being in background or being inactive you could wire your version detection into:

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

If you're interested in finding out more about the startup life-cycle and which application delegate methods are called at what points refer to the [UIApplicationDelegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive).